# Search for similar values in 2 arrays

Tags: c#, linq

I have `List<Data>` where `Data` is:

```
class Data
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Content {get;set;}
}
```

From Server I am getting following object `List<ServerData>` where `ServerData`:

```
class ServerData
{
   int sId {get;set;}
   Other stuff...
   string sContent

}
```

Using LINQ, How I can find all matches that have same `iD==sId`, `content==SContent`?

Comment: What you want do ist checking if they are equal, not if they are similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use a join ?

```
var matches = from data in listData
              join serverData in listServerData 
                  on new {id = data.Id, content = data.Content} equals 
                     new {id = serverData.sId, content = serverData.sContent}

             select new {
                 <whatever you need>
             }
```

Comment: @Servy not sure I get what you mean by "match". I can guess that in serverData public properties are needed, but is there something else ?

Comment: One has properties called `Id` and `Content`, the other `sId` and `SContent`.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus The two anonymous objects must have exactly the same names for the properties.

Comment: It is unclear by the question if a semi join as in @MatthiasG answer is wanted or a join as in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
IList<Data> data = //...
IList<ServerData> serverData = //...

IEnumerable<Data> matches = data.Where(d => 
                              serverData.Any(sd => sd.sId == d.Id && 
                                                   sd.sContent == d.Content));
```